# get/cut the first line or the first 50 words in a typescript/Js object of data

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to send only the first line or first 50 words in a variable in the data fetched by the API.

HTML File;

```
                <td *ngIf="customizedColumns?.details_of_non_conformity?.value">
                                    <span [ngClass]="{'closeLine': rpt.isDeleted == 1}">
                                    <span [tooltip]="popTemplateToolTip"
                                          triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
                                          (mouseenter)="mouseEnterToolTip(rpt.detailsOfNonConformity)"
                                          (mouseleave)="mouseLeaveToolTip()"
                                          *ngIf="rpt.detailsOfNonConformity">
                                         <span>{{helperService.removeUnwantedHTMLWithTags(rpt?.detailsOfNonConformity) | truncate:30}}</span>
                                    </span>
                                  </span>
                </td>
```

TS File:

```
  mouseEnterToolTip(data) {
    this.toolTipHtml = data.split('.')[0];
    this.toolTipHtml = this.helperService.removeUnwantedHTMLWithTags(this.toolTipHtml);
  }

  mouseLeaveToolTip() {
    this.toolTipHtml = "";
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6wHh.png)

I tried to get the first line in `data` from variable, `this.toolTipHtml = data.split('\n')[0];` I also used this but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you message what the correct input is and then what output you expect?

Comment: For Example : data = "Topic sentences are similar to mini thesis statements. Like a thesis statement, a topic sentence has a specific main point. Whereas the thesis is the main point of the essay, the topic sentence is the main point of the paragraph. ";

Comment: i need that first line data="Topic sentences are similar to mini thesis statements.";

Comment: You can use data.substring(0,50); or data.split('.')[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that returns the first line or first N words from a string.

```
getFirstSentenceOrFirstNWordsFromValue(N: number, value: string): string{
  if(!value || !N) return '';

  // Get first paragraph
  var index: number = value.indexOf("\n");
  if (index !== -1) {value = value.substring(0, index);}
  
  // Get first sentence
  index = value.indexOf(".");
  if (index !== -1) {value = value.substring(0, index + 1);};
  
  // Return first N words of remaining value
  return value.split(' ').slice(0, N).join(' ');
}
```